# Why custom component is not showing up on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I have created a custom component `InOutList` which extends `JComponent` and I want to add it on that `JFrame`. But it isn't showing up.

Here is custom component class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class InOutLists extends JComponent{
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    JPanel backPanel, p1;
    JLabel label;
    JButton btn;

    InOutLists(){
        setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 255));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        backPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p1 = new JPanel();

        label = new JLabel("Label 1");
        btn = new JButton("Back");

        p1.add(btn);
        p1.add(label);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        backPanel.add(p1, gbc);
    }
}
```

Here is main class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class CCMain extends JFrame{
    CCMain(){
        super("League Management");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1080, 780);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1080, 700));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1080, 780));
        setVisible(true);

        InOutLists iol = new InOutLists();
        add(iol, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CCMain();
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `setVisible(true);` AFTER you've added you've component

Comment: I tried.It's not working.

Comment: You now you haven't added `backPanel` to anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you want to add that as an answer? I'd just confirmed that (combined with the late `add`) is the problem before I saw your comment.

Comment: so what should i do? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sure, I was thinking of closing it as a "typo", but it might help to provide the OP with context to there numerous issues :P

Comment: sry im newbie on stackoverflow @MadProgrammer can you help me with the problem im having.?

Comment: Remove `JPanel backPanel` and `p1`. Have `InOutLists` extend `JPanel` and add the label and button to it.

Comment: That will work but i want InOutLists to extends JComponent @c0der

Comment: So leave `InOutLists extends JComponent` and apply the same solution.

Comment: No it isn't working @c0der

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If from some reason you need `backPanel` and `p1` use:  (see commented changes)

```
class InOutLists extends JComponent{

    InOutLists(){
        setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 255));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //set a layout manager to JComponent
        JPanel backPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label 1");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Back");

        p1.add(btn);
        p1.add(label);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        backPanel.add(p1, gbc);

        add(backPanel);//add backPanel to JComponent
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could add the label and button to the component :

```
class InOutLists extends JComponent{

    InOutLists(){
        setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 255));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label 1");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(label, gbc);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Back");
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(btn, gbc);
    }
}
```